# How can i remove line feed character in text file?

Tags: python, file-io, linefeed

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'tasklist'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
file = open("Process_list.txt", "r+")
for line in proc.stdout:
        file.write(str(line))

file.close()
```

i just wrote saving process list to text file. But Process_list.txt file has lots of line feed character like \r\n. How can i remove it? i used replace and strip func before

Comment: You likely want `.strip()` or `.rstrip()` (e.g. `file.write(line.rstrip())`).  Note `line` is almost definitely already a string, so converting it is unnecessary.  Also, you should look into the `with` keyword for opening files using context managers.

Comment: Actually `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` will return `bytes`. Instead of `file.write(str(line))`, do `file.write(line.decode('ascii').strip())`.

Comment: `Popen()` works with bytes so maybe you have to `encode/decode` data - or maybe you have to open file in bytes mode `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may not be so much about `replac`ing or `strip`ping extra characters as it is about what gets returned when you run `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. The latter actually returns `bytes`, which may not play so nicely with writing each line to the file. You should be able to convert the `bytes` to `string` before writing the lines to the file with the following:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'tasklist'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
file = open("Process_list.txt", "r+")
for line in proc.stdout:
        file.write(line.decode('ascii')) # to have each output in one line

file.close()
```

If you don't want to have each output in one line, then you can strip the newline characters with `file.write(line.decode('ascii').strip())`.

Moreover, you could have actually used `subprocess.getoutput` to get an output of string characters and save the outputs to your file:

```
cmd = 'tasklist'
proc = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
file.write(proc)
file.close()
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: i really appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed use `strip()` once again:

```
In [1]: 'foo\r\n'.strip()
Out[1]: 'foo'
```

In your case:

```
file.write(str(line).strip())
```

You can avoid having to `close()` your file by using `with` too:

```
with open("Process_list.txt", "r+") as file:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        file.write(str(line).strip())
```

Also, note that `str()` is only necessary of `line` is not already a string.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [str.rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip). It removes trailing newline and carriage return characters; however, it also removes all trailing whitespace, so be aware of that.